# Compare cells from multiple data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I am unsure how to approach this utilizing Pandas. I am trying to compare each ID's value in one data frame to the other data frames. An example is below.

```
Data Frame A        Data Frame B        Data Frame C
      ID    Val           ID    Val         ID      Val
0     12345 10      0     12345 11      0   12345   11
1     23456 12      1     23456 12      1   23456   12
2     34567 13      2     34567 13      2   34567   13
3     45678 16                          3   56789   12
```

Say there are three data frames (dfa, dfb, & dfc) with each having IDs and values. ID 12345 has a value of 10, 11, and 11, so it would be ignored. ID 23456 has a value of 12 for all three data frames so it would get flagged in some way. Maybe printed that ID 23456 is the same. Moving forward, the same would apply for ID 34567 since it has the same values, but ID 45678 would be ignored since it doesn't exist in data frame B or data frame C.

I've thought of some ways to do this, but it involves dictionaries and lists. I wanted to see if there was a way to better do this by continuing to utilize Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = A.merge(B,left_on='ID',right_on='ID').merge(C,left_on='ID',right_on='ID').rename({'Val_x':'Val_A','Val_y':'Val_B','Val':'Val_C'})
df['flag']=0
df.loc[(df['Val_A']==df['Val_B']) & (df['Val_B']==df['Val_C']),'flag']=1
```

The flag column is what you desire.